# Google play services error with generating OAuth2.0 client

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to test google play services features in an app that i have already published.

I went through the below link to do that.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling

When i try to authorize the app, i am getting the message
"Package name and certificate fingerprint combination already exists".

Is there a way to delete the old combination? I don't see that combination in my developer console.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same problem and once i opened my Google APIs Console, There i found already an OAuth2 key which i generate for testing purpose. I deleted that key, came back to my Game service and tried the same procedure to link and verify my game. It works. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks! Somebody already posted an answer on the same day when i put the question. This is the console link - https://console.developers.google.com/project/. I am not sure why his answer got deleted, i even accepted that as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you use the same `projectID` in google API. Do not create a new one.

Comment: put your trial code snippet with error ...so others can answer it appropriately