# Android play game services/Developer Console:"The combination of package name and certificate fingerprint already exists

Tags: android, google-play-services

I activated play game services in the Android developer console for an existing and already released app and deleted the service afterwards before releasing. Now I want to enable it again, but it says something like "The combination of package name and certificate fingerprint already exists." on app authorization. Please help..

Comment: You can verify your project if it is still existing in the "manage all project" section. The deleted project may still be there and you'll have to delete it here.

Check these SO questions [package name and certificate fingerprint combination already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714504) and [Google play services error with generating OAuth2.0 client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32605834) if these can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Right, it had to do with a "project" that initialized in the API console when I enabled the play game service. Problem is, that project does not show up in real time, but after a delay of at least minutes. Deleting it also does just mark it for deletion , what takes 7 days for finishing. Nevertheless it was possible to enable the game service on the next day again. Very confusing in the end ...

Comment: where can I find Manage All Project section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with a "project" that initialized in the API console when I enabled the play game service. Problem is, that project does not show up in real time, but after a delay of at least minutes. Deleting it also does just mark it for deletion , what takes 7 days for finishing. Nevertheless it was possible to enable the game service on the next day again. Very confusing in the end .

Another thread which seems to confirm it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27535892/7342691